# Is this a safe way to encode and decode a string in python?

Tags: python, encryption

I created a VERY simple password manager--not GUI. Basically my Python program generates a string of characters and I encode that password and then store the encoded form into an encrypted txt file. Now the catch is that I can take that encoded form and put it into my python program and it returns the original password. How safe is this? Also for whatever reason after encoding the password this is added to the password: “b’<--Password here-->’.” Now I am asking how difficult it would be for a malicious hacker to take the encoded form of the original password and get the original.

Here is my encoding code:

```
byte_pass = str.encode(password)
encoded = base64.b64encode(byte_pass)
```

Now all I have to do to return the original password is make the following:

```
base64.b64decode(old_pass)
```

And if this is not safe how can I encrypt a string using a specific keyword--almost like a master password.

Thank you!

Note** Below are some examples of the before encoding and after:

```
# Generated Password    
2]+C!)5R@hwp\zebDjOlx&xL}cRq”`n

# Encoded form of password above
b'Ml0rQyEpNVJAaHdwXHplYkRqT2x4JnhMfWNSceKAnWBu'
```

Comment: FYI, it's not hashed, it's encoded.

Comment: it's safe until somebody read your code and figure out how to decrypt any password generated by it.

Comment: No. It's not safe.  Use salted, hashed passwords.

Comment: Is there a way, then, to HASH and SALT a password and then get the original form back? Using SHA_256 Encryption?

Comment: More specifically can I get the original form from this hash:                          hash_new = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(new_password)

Comment: You can encode the code and replace chars and encode it multiple times. Opposite with decode

Comment: From this:                                                                                                                                                             from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

Comment: Add a salt to your password generator. Else if one I'd is compromised, there is a high risk of compromising all the passwords.

Comment: Use argon2: https://github.com/hynek/argon2_cffi

Answer (score 3):

> And if this is not safe how can I encrypt a string using a specific keyword--almost like a master password.

Below snippet extracted from Python's [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms).

```
from hashlib import blake2b
from hmac import compare_digest

SECRET_KEY = b'pseudorandomly generated server secret key'
AUTH_SIZE = 16 

def sign(cookie):
    h = blake2b(digest_size=AUTH_SIZE, key=SECRET_KEY)
    h.update(cookie)
    return h.hexdigest().encode('utf-8')

def verify(cookie, sig):
    good_sig = sign(cookie)
    return compare_digest(good_sig, sig)

cookie = b'user-alice'
sig = sign(cookie)
print("{0},{1}".format(cookie.decode('utf-8'), sig))

verify(cookie, sig)

verify(b'user-bob', sig)

verify(cookie, b'0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f00')
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh okay that makes much more sense as to where the “b’  ‘“ came from. Thank you.

Comment: b' ' is to denote that anything it contains is of byte type, not a string type. So if you need a string you need to convert it back.